# How to get correct time zone offset in Rails 2.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone-offset

Using Rails 2.3, when I run `ActiveSupport::TimeZone.us_zones`, I get the following:

```
....
* UTC -08:00 *
Pacific Time (US & Canada)
....
```

Now, since DST is in effect right now, the UTC offset should have been `-07:00` !

Anyone know how to get the correct Time zone offsets in Rails 2.3 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the UTC offset of the current time in that time zone:

```
zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone['Eastern Time (US & Canada)']
zone.now.utc_offset
=> -14400

zone.utc_offset
=> -18000
```